# Ionic 2 Angularfire2 auth

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

Recently I have been doing a lot of development with Angular 2. I was working on creating a project that was going to be solely a website but now that I have found Ionic 2 I am thinking I should go that way. It would be nice to have the app's along with the website but there are some things that I am not sure about. The main thing is in Angular 2 you can use Auth guards to block routes if a user is not logged in. Is this something I need to worry about when creating my ionic app? I would like to be able to run my app as a website, an android app, and ios app. If it is unnecessary that would be nice but I assume it would be needed for at least the website. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

`ionic2` doesn't use authguards. (since it doesn't work with angular's route system). I don't think that it's necessary as well, since Ionic doesn't use URL's, but rather goes with the `NavController` and navigation stack for routing.

This means that you cannot reach a page if you aren't 'pushed' towards it.

If this doesn't work or if it poses a security threat you will probably need to check on each component whether or not the user is logged in (oauth key could be stored in `localStorage` for example).

But initially, if you have for example a `Page2Component`, your html file cannot be accessed by going to `localhost:3000/page2`, but will stay on `localhost:3000` and can only be reached when `this.navCtrl.push(Page2Component)` is called.

Comment: Note: this answer is deprecated for `ionic3` since that does support routing by URL